# Generate scripts of all Indexes in Oracle PL/SQL database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to generate script of all the Indexes in Oracle database (Create Index statements). I am using PL/SQL Developer but can't find any such option.

Comment: See dbms_metadata package - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-F72B5833-C14E-4713-A588-6BDF4D4CBA2A

Answer (score 4):

A simple query like this one will generate DDL for all indexes in the database:

```sql
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL ('INDEX', INDEX_NAME, owner) FROM DBA_INDEXES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following query to get user defined Indexes:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl (object_type, object_name)
from   user_objects
where  object_type = 'INDEX'
```